# Nodejs on single page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm new on Nodejs.
I have to do a web app with node js, express, socket.io on an existing website.
I use JXcore on Parallels Plesk panel to execute node.
But when I run js file and I visit any page on the website it returns "Cannot GET ".
If I use express get() function:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var path = require('path');

app.get('/path/to/index.html', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile( path.resolve(__dirname + '/index.html') );
});

http.listen(10500, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:10500');
});
```

it works on /path/to/index.html but every other website page is blocked by the same error "Cannot GET ".
Is there a way to run node only on one page?
Thanks

Comment: Your usage of `app.get` is wrong. Please, refer to the framework documentation http://expressjs.com/

Comment: I do not think, that your problem is related with JXcore at all. Try to run the app with node on your local machine and you'll have the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing is defining just one route `/path/to/index.html` and mapping that to your index.html file. If you want to serve files from a directory, static html/css/js/whatever files, you can use the static method express provides:

```
app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + '/myHtmlDirectory'));
```

Change the "myHtmlDirectory" to whatever directory you store your files in and make sure to change the includes to define express:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

However, if you want all GET requests to point to one single file, index.html for example, you can use the following:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile( path.resolve(__dirname + '/index.html') );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code works properly, but I have the same error visiting other pages (out from /path/to/ directory). I don't understand if I cant' keep two different applications (node app and non-node app) on the same domain or if there is an error on JXCore installation on server